# Can I see who checked out what when from my subversion server?

Tags: svn, logging

Does anyone know where a log of who connected to my subversion server and what they did with it is?

I'm looking to find out what time and which files were checked out.

I'm assuming that it has something like a webserver log somewhere and I just can't find it.

EDIT:  From the response below, I wasn't aware that there are different ways of doing svn server.  I am running the svnserve as a service on windows wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what your SVN server actually is.  If it's svnserve, then it doesn't keep logs by default, and I wasn't aware that it could be configured to do so, though I might be out of date on this.

If you're using Apache/mod_svn, then you need to look into Apache logging.

Comment: If this is true than thats quite annoying. I would like to see if some contractors did indeed do a checkout as they claim.  Ugh...

Answer (score 0):

This program doesn't do exactly what you've asked for but I think it will give you the insight you're actually looking for:  CommitMonitor watches Subversion repositories for new commits and shows a notification to the user when that happens. Essentially it sits in your tray notification area and pops up an alert (like MSN) letting you know about new commits to the repository and giving you a full list of updated files - doubleclick each entry to see the diffs of each individual file.

[Commit Monitor Website](http://code.google.com/p/commitmonitor/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's interesting but as you said, not really what I'm looking for