# SVN Version control How to know if same file is under use by other team mate

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, version-control

I want to ask about version control that we are using. And it is SVN. I am working on a project with other team members and using SVN as version control.

So it is very easy to understand and to work with. But There is one problem and that is sometimes it happen that me and my other team member start working on same file. And in the end of the day we have to merge the differences in file to settle issues down.

But my point is, Is not it far batter to know before starting work on same file that It is already under working of any team member.

I have been searching for it for hours but did not get any help.

**Can someone please tell me How to do it in SVN That is provided in Android studio and on server side we are using SVN Standard Edition 3.5.10???**

> **Note:** We are using SVN and we can not change this version control at
> the moment.

Comment: Have you seen [Can I see who checked out what when from my subversion server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359665/295004). Which implies that audit features may depend on which version of SVN you are using. Also [How can I determine who locked a file using SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/853328/295004)

Comment: These threads are so old. And I did not get any help from them

Comment: You should mention which SVN server you are using and if command line is an acceptable workaround. Also if the links didn't help, explain what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: The one that is provided in Android studio @MorrisonChang

Comment: That is a client which connects to a server. I'm going to assume you didn't find what you want in the [Intellij Subversion Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-subversion-integration.html) My question is "What Subversion server/repository source are you using?" as the solution would be at the repository source end rather than client, which is covered by my links, or use the command line client.

Comment: I have looked into the link you provided. It has information but not the one that I wanted to know. @MorrisonChang

Comment: @MorrisonChang question updated with svn version

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html and details of user-side implementation are *dependent*